# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - Extract inner attributes

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm trying to extract the lat/long coordinates from the following $html text:

```
<div class="marker" data-lat="60.29805979999999" data-lng="19.07932260000007"></div>
```

By doing `$html->find(div[class="marker"])` just gives me an empty array? So how would I extract the inner attributes within the same div to get the coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution with PHP Simple HTML DOM parser at least:

```
foreach ($html->find('div[class=marker]') as $e) { 
            echo "Latitude : ".$e->getAttribute("data-lat") ."<br>";
            echo "Longitude : ".$e->getAttribute("data-lng") ."<br>";
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jquery you could do:

```
$('.marker').attr('data-lat').val();
$('.marker').attr('data-lng').val();
```

In JS you could do

```
document.getElementsByClass("marker").getAttribute("data-lat");
document.getElementsByClass("marker").getAttribute("data-lng");
```